# Merge tags request: floating point precision

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Browsing through tags related to the representation of floating point numbers on SO I noticed a couple of tags which should presumably be merged and synonyms created:

- [floating-accuracy](/questions/tagged/floating-accuracy) and [floating-point-precision](/questions/tagged/floating-point-precision) should be merged, as should [double](/questions/tagged/double) and [double-precision](/questions/tagged/double-precision).
- [single-precision](/questions/tagged/single-precision) already exists, as does [half-precision-float](/questions/tagged/half-precision-float). Based on this later tag, should [single-precision](/questions/tagged/single-precision) and [double-precision](/questions/tagged/double-precision) actually be [single-precision-float](/questions/tagged/single-precision-float) and [double-precision-float](/questions/tagged/double-precision-float) respectively? I think having the `-float` suffix makes the purpose of the tags more explicit.
- Furthermore, I think that many questions in [precision](/questions/tagged/precision) and possibly some in [numeric-precision](/questions/tagged/numeric-precision) should really be tagged [floating-point-precision](/questions/tagged/floating-point-precision).
- I'm not sure where [floating-point](/questions/tagged/floating-point) should fit in to all of this.

I just wanted to raise the above points and see what the community thinks. I'm not really sure what the process for mass renaming/synonyms creation is.

<strike>Also, similar, but not actually related to floating point numbers are the tags [floated](/questions/tagged/floated), [floating](/questions/tagged/floating) and [css-float](/questions/tagged/css-float). Presumably these should all be moved/mapped to [css-float](/questions/tagged/css-float)?</strike>

**Update:** So the CSS related tags have largely been sorted thanks to animuson. Does anyone have any suggestions for the floating point related tags?

Comment: [tag:floated] is dead, and all the [tag:floating] questions also tagged with [tag:css] have been retagged. Merging can't be done, as the very first question listed for that tag is related to Ubuntu stuff.